# How to properly call a method in Java

Tags: java, merge

I have the following code on the merge sort algorithm. Not having used Java for some time, I have completely forgotten how to properly call the method MergeSort in order for it to order some specified array. Currently, `MergeSort(A)` is throwing an error (because the method MergeSort is generic?). It is telling me that I should instead have my MergeSort signature as `MergeSort(int[] A)`. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] A = {4,7,9,2,3,3,0,1};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(A));

    MergeSort(A);
}


public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void MergeSort(T[] A){
    MergeSort(A, 0, A.length - 1);
}

private static <T extends Comparable<T>> void MergeSort(T[] A, int p, int r){
    if(p < r){
        int q =  (p + r)/2;
        MergeSort(A,p,q);
        MergeSort(A,q + 1, r);
        merge(A,p,q,r);
    }
}

private static <T extends Comparable<T>> void merge(T[] A, int p, int q, int r){
    T[] temp = (T[])(new Comparable[A.length]);

    int first1 = p, last1 = q;
    int first2 = q + 1, last2 = r;
    int index = first1;

    while(first1 <= last1 && first2 <= last2){
        if(A[first1].compareTo(A[first2]) < 0){
            temp[index] = A[first1];
            first1++;
        } else {
            temp[index] = A[first2];
            first2++;
        }
        index++;
    }

    while(first1 <= last1){
        temp[index] = A[first1];
        first1++; index++;
    }
    while(first2 <= last2){
        temp[index] = A[first2];
        first2++; index++;
    }

    for(index = p; index <= r; index++){
        A[index] = temp[index];
    }
}
```

Comment: `int` is not a `Type`. It's primitive. That's why `Arrays` class static methods all has alternatives for each primitive type array.

Comment: Make sure to include the exact error message in questions. (Also, remember to search for it first.)

Answer (score 1):

This error is because `int` is a primitive, and arrays of primitives can't be used as generic arrays.

What you can do is to use the corresponding wrapper type `Integer` instead. Declare your array as

```
Integer[] A = {4,7,9,2,3,3,0,1};
```

and it will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void MergeSort(T[] A)
```

Ignoring the naming of variables, I will talk about that at the end, you need an array of `T` where `T extends Comparable<T>`.

You have `int[] A`. As `int` is a primitive and cannot `extends` anything, this cannot possibly work. You need an `Integer[]`:

```
Integer[] A = {4,7,9,2,3,3,0,1};
```

I would also point out, that unless this is an academic exercise, the [`Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) utility class in the Java API has many different `sort()` methods for exactly this reason, including [one for `int[]`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-int:A-).

**Now, naming.**

In Java it is the accepted and strongly encouraged convention to use `camelCase` for variables; `PascalCase` for classes and `BLOCK_CAPS` for compile time constants. Please change your code to comply as not doing so makes it very tough to read. Moreover, it messes up the automatic syntax highlighting here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

As the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4) has stated that:

```
Every type variable declared as a type parameter has a bound. 
If no bound is declared for a type variable, Object is assumed.
```

since you passed a primitive type it will generate compile time error that the method `MergeSort` expects a `type variable` not a `primitive type`.

**solution:**

You can use the wrapper class of the integer primitive which is `Integer`.

```
Integer[] A = {4,7,9,2,3,3,0,1};
```